# Browser error Javascript and Html onclick

Tags: javascript

The form and javascript work when I run it as simple html.
But when I install wordpress it gives an error as (custom html) code.
What could be the problem?

The error I get in the browser is as follows;

> Error name (Uncaught ReferenceError: recalc_onclick is not defined at
> HTMLInputElement.onclick )

```
<script language="JavaScript">var agt = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var NS4 = (document.layers);    // Which browser?
var IE4 = (document.all);

var win = window;    // window to search.
var n   = 0;
var str = "xxx.com"

function findLinkInPage(str) {


  // Find next occurance of the given string on the page, wrap around to the
  // start of the page if necessary.

if (agt.indexOf("msie") != -1){
  var txt = win.document.body.createTextRange();
  var i, found;
  if (IE4) {

    // Find the nth match from the top of the page.

    for (i = 0; i <= n && (found = txt.findText(str)) != false; i++) {
    }

    // If found, mark it and scroll it into view.

    if (found) {
return true;
    }

    // Otherwise, start over at the top of the page and find first match.

    else {
      if (n > 0) {
        n = 0;
        findLinkInPage(str);
      }

      // Not found anywhere, give message.

      else
        alert("Link to xxx.com is not found or changed.");
    }
  }

}
    else {
return true;
      }

}

var co = new Object;

function recalc_onclick(ctl) {
findLinkInPage(str);

  if (document.formc.automatic_recalc.checked || ctl=='') {




co.pA1B=document.formc.pA1B[document.formc.pA1B.selectedIndex].value;co.pA2B=eeparseFloat(document.formc.pA2B.value);co.pA2C=document.formc.pA2C[document.formc.pA2C.selectedIndex].value;co.pA3B=eeparseFloat(document.formc.pA3B.value);co.pA3C=document.formc.pA3C[document.formc.pA3C.selectedIndex].value;co.pA4B=eeparseFloatV(document.formc.pA4B[document.formc.pA4B.selectedIndex].value);co.pA5B=document.formc.pA5B[document.formc.pA5B.selectedIndex].value;co.pA6G=eeparseFloat(document.formc.pA6G.value);co.pA6H=document.formc.pA6H[document.formc.pA6H.selectedIndex].value;co.pA6M=eeparseFloat(document.formc.pA6M.value);co.pA6N=document.formc.pA6N[document.formc.pA6N.selectedIndex].value;calc(co);document.formc.pA2D.value=eedisplayFloat(co.pA2D);document.formc.pA3D.value=eedisplayFloat(co.pA3D);document.formc.pA6B.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA6B,2);document.formc.pA6J.value=eedisplayFloat(co.pA6J);document.formc.pA6O.value=eedisplayFloat(co.pA6O);document.formc.pA7B.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA7B,2);document.formc.pA7F.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA7F,2);document.formc.pA7L.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA7L,2);document.formc.pA8B.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA8B,2);document.formc.pA8D.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA8D,2);document.formc.pA8F.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA8F,2);document.formc.pA8H.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA8H,2);document.formc.pA8L.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA8L,2);document.formc.pA8N.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA8N,2);document.formc.pA9B.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA9B,2);document.formc.pA9D.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA9D,2);document.formc.pA9F.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA9F,2);document.formc.pA9H.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA9H,2);document.formc.pA9L.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA9L,2);document.formc.pA9N.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA9N,2);document.formc.pA10B.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA10B,2);document.formc.pA10D.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA10D,2);document.formc.pA10F.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA10F,2);document.formc.pA10H.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA10H,2);document.formc.pA10L.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA10L,2);document.formc.pA10N.value=eedisplayFloatND(co.pA10N,2);

};};



var eeisus=1;var eetrue="TRUE";var eefalse="FALSE";var eedec=".";var eeth=",";var eedecreg=new RegExp("[.]","g");var eethreg=new RegExp(",","g");


function calc(data){var cA1B=data.pA1B;var cA2B=data.pA2B;var cA2C=data.pA2C;var cA3B=data.pA3B;var cA3C=data.pA3C;var cA4B=data.pA4B;var cA5B=data.pA5B;var cA6G=data.pA6G;var cA6H=data.pA6H;var cA6M=data.pA6M;var cA6N=data.pA6N;var cA21A=("Sedentary (little or no exercise, desk job)");var cA22A=("Lightly active (light exercise/sports 1-3 days/wk)");var cA23A=("Moderately active (moderate exercise/sports 3-5 days/wk)");var cA24A=("Very active (hard exercise/sports 6-7 days/wk)");var cA25A=("Extremely active (hard daily exercise/sports & physical job)");var cA2D=(((str_eq((cA2C),("centimetres")))?(cA2B):(((cA2B)*(2.54)))));var cA3D=(((str_eq((cA3C),("kilograms")))?(cA3B):(((cA3B)*(0.4536)))));var cA6B=(((str_eq((cA1B),("Male")))?(((((((66)+(((13.7)*(cA3D)))))+(((5)*(cA2D)))))-(((6.8)*(v2n(cA4B)))))):(((((((655)+(((9.6)*(cA3D)))))+(((1.8)*(cA2D)))))-(((4.7)*(v2n(cA4B))))))));var cA6J=(((str_eq((cA6H),("pounds")))?(cA6G):(((cA6G)*(2.2)))));var cA6O=(((str_eq((cA6N),("pounds")))?(cA6M):(((cA6M)*(2.2)))));var cA7B=(((str_eq((cA5B),(cA21A)))?(((cA6B)*(1.2))):(((str_eq((cA5B),(cA22A)))?(((cA6B)*(1.375))):(((str_eq((cA5B),(cA23A)))?(((cA6B)*(1.55))):(((str_eq((cA5B),(cA24A)))?(((cA6B)*(1.725))):(((str_eq((cA5B),(cA25A)))?(((cA6B)*(1.9))):(0)))))))))));var cA7F=(((cA7B)-(((500)*(cA6J)))));var cA7L=(((cA7B)+(((500)*(cA6O)))));var cA8B=(((cA7B)*(0.55)));var cA9B=(((cA7B)*(0.15)));var cA10B=(((cA7B)*(0.3)));var cA8D=(((cA8B)*(0.25)));var cA8F=(((cA7F)*(0.55)));var cA8L=(((cA7L)*(0.55)));var cA9D=(((cA9B)*(0.25)));var cA9F=(((cA7F)*(0.15)));var cA9L=(((cA7L)*(0.15)));var cA10D=(((cA10B)*(0.1111)));var cA10F=(((cA7F)*(0.3)));var cA10L=(((cA7L)*(0.3)));var cA8H=(((cA8F)*(0.25)));var cA8N=(((cA8L)*(0.25)));var cA9H=(((cA9F)*(0.25)));var cA9N=(((cA9L)*(0.25)));var cA10H=(((cA10F)*(0.1111)));var cA10N=(((cA10L)*(0.1111)));data.pA2D=cA2D;data.pA3D=cA3D;data.pA6B=cA6B;data.pA6J=cA6J;data.pA6O=cA6O;data.pA7B=cA7B;data.pA7F=cA7F;data.pA7L=cA7L;data.pA8B=cA8B;data.pA8D=cA8D;data.pA8F=cA8F;data.pA8H=cA8H;data.pA8L=cA8L;data.pA8N=cA8N;data.pA9B=cA9B;data.pA9D=cA9D;data.pA9F=cA9F;data.pA9H=cA9H;data.pA9L=cA9L;data.pA9N=cA9N;data.pA10B=cA10B;data.pA10D=cA10D;data.pA10F=cA10F;data.pA10H=cA10H;data.pA10L=cA10L;data.pA10N=cA10N;};


function str_eq(x,y){return(x.toLowerCase()==y.toLowerCase())};function myIsNaN(x){return(isNaN(x)||(typeof x=='number'&&!isFinite(x)));};function round(n,nd){if(isFinite(n)&&isFinite(nd)){var sign_n=(n<0)?-1:1;var abs_n=Math.abs(n);var factor=Math.pow(10,nd);return sign_n*Math.round(abs_n*factor)/factor;}else{return NaN;}};function s2n(str){str=String(str).replace(eedecreg,".");return parseFloat(str);}function v2n(v){switch(typeof v){case "number":return v;case "string":return s2n(v);case "boolean":return v?1:0;case "object":if(v.constructor==Number){return v;};if(v.constructor==String){return s2n(v);};if(v.constructor==Boolean){return v?1:0;};return Number.NaN;default:return Number.NaN;}};function eeparseFloat(str){str=String(str).replace(eedecreg,".");var res=parseFloat(str);if(isNaN(res)){return 0;}else{return res;}};function eedisplayFloat(x){if(myIsNaN(x)){return Number.NaN;}else{return String(x).replace(/\./g,eedec);}};function eedisplayFloatND(x,nd){if(myIsNaN(x)){return Number.NaN;}else{var res=round(x,nd);if(nd>0){var str=String(res);if(str.indexOf('e')!=-1)return str;if(str.indexOf('E')!=-1)return str;var parts=str.split('.');if(parts.length<2){var decimals=('00000000000000').substring(0,nd);return(parts[0]).toString()+eedec+decimals;}else{var decimals=((parts[1]).toString()+'00000000000000').substring(0,nd);return(parts[0]).toString()+eedec+decimals;}}else{return res;}}};var eeparseFloatVreg=new RegExp("^ *-?[0-9.]+ *$");function eeparseFloatV(str){if(str=="")return str;str=String(str).replace(eedecreg,".");if(!eeparseFloatVreg.test(str)){return str;};var res=parseFloat(str);if(isNaN(res)){return str;}else{return res;}};

</script>
<form id="formc" name="formc" action="" method="post">
<h5>Lütfen Bilgilerinizi Giriniz.</h5>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Cinsiyetiniz</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<select class="form-control" name="pA1B" id="pA1B" size="1" onchange="recalc_onclick('pA1B')" tabindex="1">
<option value="Male" selected="selected">Erkek</option>
<option value="Female">Kadın</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Yaşınız</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<select class="form-control" name="pA4B" id="pA4B" size="1" onchange="recalc_onclick('pA4B')" tabindex="6" style="width:100%">
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30" selected="selected">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
<option value="32">32</option>
<option value="33">33</option>
<option value="34">34</option>
<option value="35">35</option>
<option value="36">36</option>
<option value="37">37</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="41">41</option>
<option value="42">42</option>
<option value="43">43</option>
<option value="44">44</option>
<option value="45">45</option>
<option value="46">46</option>
<option value="47">47</option>
<option value="48">48</option>
<option value="49">49</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="51">51</option>
<option value="52">52</option>
<option value="53">53</option>
<option value="54">54</option>
<option value="55">55</option>
<option value="56">56</option>
<option value="57">57</option>
<option value="58">58</option>
<option value="59">59</option>
<option value="60">60</option>
<option value="61">61</option>
<option value="62">62</option>
<option value="63">63</option>
<option value="64">64</option>
<option value="65">65</option>
<option value="66">66</option>
<option value="67">67</option>
<option value="68">68</option>
<option value="69">69</option>
<option value="70">70</option>
<option value="71">71</option>
<option value="72">72</option>
<option value="73">73</option>
<option value="74">74</option>
<option value="75">75</option>
<option value="76">76</option>
<option value="77">77</option>
<option value="78">78</option>
<option value="79">79</option>
<option value="80">80</option>
<option value="81">81</option>
<option value="82">82</option>
<option value="83">83</option>
<option value="84">84</option>
<option value="85">85</option>
<option value="86">86</option>
<option value="87">87</option>
<option value="88">88</option>
<option value="89">89</option>
<option value="90">90</option>
<option value="91">91</option>
<option value="92">92</option>
<option value="93">93</option>
<option value="94">94</option>
<option value="95">95</option>
<option value="96">96</option>
<option value="97">97</option>
<option value="98">98</option>
<option value="99">99</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Boyunuz</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input name="pA2B" id="pA2B" type="text" value="180" onblur="this.value=eedisplayFloat(eeparseFloat(this.value));recalc_onclick('pA2B')" tabindex="2" style="width:100%" class="form-control">
</div>
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Birim</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<select class="form-control" name="pA2C" id="pA2C" size="1" onchange="recalc_onclick('pA2C')" tabindex="3">
<option value="centimetres" selected="">cm</option>
<option value="inches">inc</option>
</select>
<input name="pA2D" id="pA2D" type="text" readonly="true" class="ee101" size="10" style="visibility: hidden; width: 5">

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Kilonuz</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="form-control" name="pA3B" id="pA3B" type="text" value="80" onblur="this.value=eedisplayFloat(eeparseFloat(this.value));recalc_onclick('pA3B')" tabindex="4" style="width:100%" size="8">
</div>
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Birim</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<select class="form-control" name="pA3C" id="pA3C" size="1" onchange="recalc_onclick('pA3C')" tabindex="5">
<option value="kilograms" selected="">Kg</option>
<option value="pounds">Lb</option>
</select>
<input name="pA3D" id="pA3D" type="text" value="0" readonly="true" class="ee101" size="4" style="visibility: hidden; width: 5">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<h5>Günlük Aktivite Bilgilerinizi Giriniz.</h5>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<select class="form-control" name="pA5B" id="pA5B" size="1" onchange="recalc_onclick('pA5B')" tabindex="7">
<option value="Sedentary (little or no exercise, desk job)">Hareketsiz (Az, Hareketsiz, Masa Başı İş)</option>
<option value="Lightly active (light exercise/sports 1-3 days/wk)">Hafif Aktivite (1-3 Gün Arası Spor ve Az Hareketli)</option>
<option value="Moderately active (moderate exercise/sports 3-5 days/wk)" selected="selected">Orta Derece Aktivite(3-5 Gün Arası Spor ve Orta Hareketli)</option>
<option value="Very active (hard exercise/sports 6-7 days/wk)">Yoğun Aktivite (Aktif Egzersiz ve Spor)</option>
<option value="Extremely active (hard daily exercise/sports &amp; physical job)">Ekstreme Aktivite (Günlük Egzersiz, Spor ve AKtif İş Temposu)</option>
</select>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="col-x1-12">
<br> 
</div>
</div><div class="col-md-6">
<div class="col-x1-12">
<br><input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--red" type="button" value="Hesapla" name="automatic_recalc"  onclick="recalc_onclick('')">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="donate-form-area">
<div class="donate-form-wrapper">
<div class="sec-title">
<div class="text">Günlük kalori hesaplama aracı kilo verme, kilo alma ve kilonuzu korumanız için size ipuçları verir.</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group contact-form">
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input type="text" value="Bazal Metabolik Oranı : " tabindex="2" style="width:100%" class="alert alert-primary alert-simple alert-inline">
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="col-md-6">
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA6B" id="pA6B" value="0" readonly="true" size="8">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<h3>Kilonuzu korumak için almanız gereken kalori :</h3>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Toplam Günlük Kaloriniz</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA7B" id="pA7B" value="0" readonly="true" size="7">
</div></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Karbonhidratlar (%55)</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA8B" id="pA8B" value="0" readonly="true" size="8"><input name="pA8D" id="pA8D" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div></div></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Proteinler (%15)</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA9B" id="pA9B" value="0" readonly="true" size="7"><input name="pA9D" id="pA9D" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Yağlar</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA10B" id="pA10B" value="0" readonly="true" size="8"><input name="pA10D" id="pA10D" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div>
</div></div>
<hr>
<h3>Kilo Verme Gereksinimleri :</h3>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Haftalık Hedef Kilonuzu Belirtiniz</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="form-control" name="pA6G" id="pA6G" type="text" value="1" onblur="this.value=eedisplayFloat(eeparseFloat(this.value));recalc_onclick('pA6G')" tabindex="8" size="2" style="width:100%">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Birim</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<select class="form-control" name="pA6H" id="select" size="1" onchange="recalc_onclick('pA6H')" tabindex="9">
<option value="kilograms" selected="selected">kg</option>
<option value="pounds">lb</option>
</select>
<input class="theme-btn btn-style-two" name="pA6J" id="pA6J2" type="text" value="0" readonly="true" style="visibility: hidden; width:100%">
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Kalori</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA7F" id="pA7F" value="0" readonly="true" size="7">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Karbonhidratlar (%55)</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA8F" id="pA8F" value="0" readonly="true" size="8"><input name="pA8H" id="pA8H2" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Proteinler (%15)</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA9F" id="pA9F" value="0" readonly="true" size="7"><input name="pA9H" id="pA9H2" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Yağlar</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA10F" id="pA10F" value="0" readonly="true" size="8"><input name="pA10H" id="pA10H2" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div>
</div></div>
<hr>
<h3>Kilo Alma Gereksinimleri :</h3>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Haftalık Hedef Kilonuzu Belirtiniz</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="form-control" name="pA6M" id="pA6M2" type="text" value="1" onblur="this.value=eedisplayFloat(eeparseFloat(this.value));recalc_onclick('pA6M')" tabindex="8" size="2" style="width:100%">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Birim</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<select class="form-control" name="pA6N" id="select2" size="1" onchange="recalc_onclick('pA6N')" tabindex="11">
<option value="kilograms" selected="selected">kg</option>
<option value="pounds">lb</option>
</select>
<input name="pA6O" id="pA6O2" type="text" value="0" readonly="true" class="ee101" size="2" style="visibility: hidden; width:100%">
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Kalori</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA7L" id="pA7L" value="0" readonly="true" size="7">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Karbonhidratlar (%55)</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA8L" id="pA8L" value="0" readonly="true" size="8"><input name="pA8N" id="pA8N2" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Proteinler (%15)</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA9L" id="pA9L" value="0" readonly="true" size="7"><input name="pA9N" id="pA9N2" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="col-x1-12 control-label"><font color="1f232d" class="h2">Yağlar</font></label>
<div class="col-x1-12">
<input class="uckan-btn uckan-btn-- uckan-btn--block uckan-btn--white" name="pA10L" id="pA10L" value="0" readonly="true" size="8"><input name="pA10N" id="pA10N2" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>recalc_onclick('');</script>
</div>
</div></form>
```

Comment: try to rename the "recalc_onclick" to "recalc_whenclick"

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: recalc_whenclick is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (?page_id=10827&preview=true:844:160)

It didn't happen :(

Comment: are you set the: onchange="recalc_onclick( ... to onchange="recalc_whenclick( ... ?

Comment: yes "recalc_onclick" all replace to "recalc_whenclick"

Comment: Where are you putting this code?

Comment: I want to run it by adding (Custom Html) to the Wordpress page part.